# ?? Operator - Using in one liner condition

Tags: c#

Can someone explain how the below statement operates. I know that the ?? operator returns the first argument if it is not null. But I was a little confused when I saw the ? following the 'file' variable.

```
return file?.ImportStatus ?? ImportStatusEnum.Unknown;
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because null propagation operator is not mentioned in the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a combination of [*null propagation*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and *null coalesce* operators.

It will produce `ImportStatusEnum.Unknown` in the following cases:

- **`file` is `null`** - In this case, `.ImportStatus` is not evaluated, and the left side of `??` becomes `null`, or
- **`file` is not `null`, but `ImportStatus` is `null`** - in this case, the left side of `??` is also `null`, so the right side is used.

If neither `file` nor its `ImportStatus` are `null`, then the value of `file.ImportStatus` will be used as the result of the overall expression.

Answer (score 5):

@dasblinkenlight is correct, just to show it a different way, it could be written like this (in order of evaluation):

```
if (file == null) return ImportStatusEnum.Unknown;
if (file.ImportStatus  != null) 
    return file.ImportStatus;
else 
    return ImportStatusEnum.Unknown;
```

Comment: OK, my mistake, the evaluation is still continues with the following ?? apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the compiler will generate **different** code based on whether the `ImportStatus` is *nullable* or not. If it is NOT nullable, so like this:

```
public ImportStatusEnum ImportStatus {get; set;}
```

then the compiler will generate this:

```
return file != null ? file.ImportStatus : ImportStatusEnum.Unknown;
```

which is the same as

```
if (file != null)
    return file.ImportStatus;
return ImportStatusEnum.Unknown;
```

If the property is *nullable*, so like this:

```
public ImportStatusEnum? ImportStatus {get; set;}
//OR
public Nullable<ImportStatusEnum> ImportStatus {get; set;}
```

then it will do what @dasblinkenlight and @garethb have indicated in their answers.